# Loop Java program with bash

Tags: java, bash, loops

I need to execute a java program in shell looply.

The program is really basic. I'm getting an access token and I'm using it to make a simple POST request.

**My problem :**

- I need to refresh the access token every 55 minutes (the token has an hour expiration)
- I need to make the POST every 5 min

I don't know which timer I should use in my shell command(and in my code ?)

If I put 5 min, this will refresh the token every 5 min...

Sorry I didn't provide any code, it's just an issue I don't know how to solve.

Thanks !

Comment: why don't you put the loop in your java app?

Comment: Use `cron`, not a loop

Comment: Use `cron jobs` to run your `bash script`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in Linux you may use cron:
Edit the /etc/crontab file and add a new line like this:

```
*/5 * * * * java -jar <your jar> <params>
```

This will run your program every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood correctly. In bash you would like something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
echo "refresh token";
a=0;

while true; do

  echo "doing post"
  echo "sleeping 5 minutes here"
  sleep 300;
  a=$[$a+1]

  if [ $a -eq 11 ]; then
    a=0
    echo "refreshing token again"
  fi

done;

done
```

Just translate it to java.